# Why is there null in front of my fresh String?

Tags: java, string, apache-commons

I have the following function, the input is just a simple String.

```
public X509CertificateHandler getCertByFingerprint(String thumbPrint) {
    if (_thumbprintMap.containsKey(thumbPrint)) {
        return _thumbprintMap.get(thumbPrint);
    }
}
```

So in my test case, I am just hardcoding the value just to test it out, however I need them to be uppercase, so I throw it into Apache Common, simple right?

```
certs.getCertByFingerprint(StringUtils.upperCase("‎eb55b661dd9133bc564aa259bcd0c598ce02892f"));
```

Now the funny thing is that, once I step into my function, the String value being pass into the function is different than I expected!

For some reason, there seems to be a `null` of some sort at the beginning of the variable! Putting it in my expression watch, I get the following:

[image]

As you can see, there is an extra `[,` character in front of the string... This is the reason why I couldn't find what I am looking for from my array! But why?

To make sure I am not crazy, I ran the following:

```
String fingerprint = "‎eb55b661dd9133bc564aa259bcd0c598ce02892f";
String f2 = StringUtils.upperCase(fingerprint);
f2.equals(fingerprint);
```

Since I am initialize the string, there is no way that I get a `null` in front of it.. but still, the above code still gave me `[,` in front of my fresh string... wtf?

Comment: Your method doesn't compile.

Comment: "For some reason, there seems to be a null of some sort at the beginning of the variable!" That is virtually impossible. A `String` in Java uses a `char[]` as its backing storage and you cannot store `null` values in a primitive array. And the `[` is part of the `String`-representation fo the array, not a character. There should be a `]` on the right side.

Comment: @Turing85 I know, which is why it drives me crazy. If you look at my screenshot, the 1st row is when I use the variable, the 2nd row I use the hardcoded value. It couldn't find the key in my Map, but it does if I provide the hardcode value.

Comment: There's nothing in your screenshot or anywhere else that indicates a null value. As @Turing85 said, there's no such thing as a null primitive.

Comment: Yeah well, what i mean by `null` is just something invisible there, was what I mean. Because I see a comma in the array but nothing there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an invisible character at the beginning of your string, the [LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm). Try running this line:

```
System.out.println(
        "eb55b661dd9133bc564aa259bcd0c598ce02892f".length() < 
        "‎eb55b661dd9133bc564aa259bcd0c598ce02892f".length()
);
```

Output:

```
true
```

They *look* identical, but the second one has your hidden character. Grab the first string and you should be good.

Comment: OMFG, that's it... I can't believe it... I grabbed the string from the Microsoft's certificate window by copy paste. I had no idea where the heck the invisible char came from. I even turned on the line markers from Eclipse lol... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First let me talk shortly about your first assumption regarding the `null` value. When you take a look at the implementation of `String`, you will see that a `String` uses a `char[]` as backing storage. In Java, it is impossible to store a `null` value in a primitive array.

There is, however, an invisible character between the `"` and the `e` in this line of code:

```
String fingerprint      = "‎eb55b661dd9133bc564aa259bcd0c598ce02892f";
String fingerprintFixed = "eb55b661dd9133bc564aa259bcd0c598ce02892f";
```

As is shown [in shmosel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43946559/4216641), these `String`s have different lengths.
Just set your cursor between `"` and `e`, hit the delete key and you should be good to go (or copy `fingerprintFixed` from above).

Comment: I would've accept your answer too, but I took @shmosel 's answer as he replied first in both occasions. Thank!